# Turn symbol into string in a text field through rails migration

Tags: ruby-on-rails, migration

I have a text field in the database that contains symbols, strings, numbers etc.
I need to change part of the data:
`\nassigned_x:\n- :assigned_y\n- :assigned_to\n- :follow\n`

For example, I need to change these symbols to string in the database and I created a migration for this:

```
def change
    statuses = [:assigned_x, :assigned_y, :follow]
    setting = Setting.last.data
    statuses.each do |status|
      setting.gsub!(status.to_s, status.to_s) if setting.include?(status.to_s)
    end
  end
```

However, none of these values were updated. Could you please help me with this migration? Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Issues:**

- You are assigning an attribute to the `setting` variable and trying to save it using `gsub!`
- The `gsub!` never saves anything in the database
- Also the data would never persist in database until you run `object.save`

Try this:

```
def change
  statuses = [:assigned_x, :assigned_y, :follow]
  setting_obj = Setting.last
  setting_data = setting_obj.data
  statuses.each do |status|
    next unless setting_data.include?(status.to_s)

    setting_data = setting_data.gsub(status.to_s, status.to_s)
  end
  setting_obj.data = setting_data
  setting_obj.save
end
```

You might have to debug and correct the first parameter to `gsub` method according to the String saved in database